# Placing Realm database on sdcard and using it from there - Android

Tags: android, realm

Is there anyway that i can choose the path of the Realm database, So that the database will be there, and the app will be using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm Configuration Builder does allow configuring the [folder path](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/). So, you should be able to point it to the appropriate sdcard folder. Example:

```
File folder = new File("/data/user/0/...");
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(folder).build();
```

You can also check if it was properly set by:
`realmConfig.getRealmFolder().getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 2):

The Realm Configuration Builder now has two methods to define the database path and filename:

- builder.**directory()**
- builder.**name()**

Example of the methods to use in you application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    initializeRealm();
}

private void initializeRealm() {

    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration.Builder realmBuilder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder();
    realmBuilder.directory(new File(getRealmPath(this)));
    realmBuilder.name("realmDataBase.realm");

    RealmConfiguration config = realmBuilder.build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}

public String getRealmPath(Context context) {

    String externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    return externalStorageDir + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + packageName + File.separator + "realm" + File.separator;
}
```

Comment: i try to access Realm.getDefaultConfiguration().getPath() its whitens default data/data/package/files instead custom one

Comment: Try with Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmDirectory()